How to get the filename without the extension from a string url?
I am trying to get file name without extension that is located at the end of a string url.
Here is what I have and tried:
I have url: "https://res.cloudinary.com/hspa2024/image/upload/v000000/test2/ramicard.jpg" and I need to get the file name "ramicard" without the extension, how to do that?
I tried:
myurl.Split("/").ToString();

I am getting System.String[] instead.

You can use the built in "Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension". It works for both urls and file paths (have you seen a file path on a non Windows system? They are basically urls).
var filenameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("https://res.cloudinary.com/hspa2024/image/upload/v000000/test2/ramicard.jpg")

Example on SharpLab

It's simple with the System.Uri class.
var uri = new Uri("https://res.cloudinary.com/hspa2024/image/upload/v000000/test2/ramicard.jpg");
var filename = uri.Segments.Last().Split('.').First();

That gives ramicard.

Using Uri to deconstruct a URI is exactly what it's for. I'm surprised to get a down-vote for it.

Using First or FirstOrDefault to get the file name without extension is clearly incorrect.

@shingo - No, with Split the .First() is guaranteed to have a first element.

For example, if the file name is red.tar.gz, the file name without extension should be red.tar, but your method will result in red.
